# Duplicating an observable bound to a dialogue

Tags: knockout.js

I have a foreach (over Foos) table where a user clicks on an item and this method is called:

```
 AddFoo = function (addingItem) {
        var addingItem = jQuery.extend(true, {}, existingObservableBoundToJqueryDialogue);
        this.Foos.push(addingItem);  //EditingItem is bound to the add dialogue, and I want a new observable with the same properties not bound to the dialogue

    };
```

the trouble I have is that if I go and edit this observable(the new addingItem ) in the table, it changes all the items(each addingItem ) that were added this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very quick solution is to use [knockout mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin to create plain vanilla json object and then new knockout model from it:

```
var addingItem = ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.mapping.toJS(existingObservableBoundToJqueryDialogue));
```

This will unwrap observable and then create another from its values :)

[Working sample on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BvCL2/)

Comment: ah so it keeps the observable type, very clever!

Comment: Yes, if it is not observable, then there is no two-way binding. Btw, if you have a model which is not edited (not bound to input fields) then it is ok to have non-observable fields (it may even be few miliseconds faster ;))

Comment: thanks again! Cool post on Script resource localization in ASP.NET MVC btw!

Comment: btw in  your fiddle, is a: "blah",
    b: "elah" typed to observables?

Comment: Thanks; Yes, a and b are observables (mapping plugin converts plain json to observables), you can see that from setting values after binding, it is like b("newvalue"), not b = "newvalue"

Comment: I see I wonder why this .mapping isn't included out of the box.

Comment: Don't know, probably they wanted to have as small codebase as possible, because it is easier to support and develop features that way. If you did not know about it, you may also want to check out http://www.johnpapa.net/kolite1-1/